# Forcing the app to create tables without seed method, using code-first approach

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Due to some reasons (too long story) I can't use automatic code first migrations. But I would need to be able to create SQL script for creating tables (any other way with the same result is good as well) in my database based on the model, without writing the Seed method? Sometimes I don't need any seeding, just creating tables would suit my needs as I have to test creating records anyway. But I cant't find a way to do. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use migrations to generate a script with `-script` rather than updating the database directly with `update-database`.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project WebApplication10.
PM> Add-Migration Initial
Scaffolding migration 'Initial'.
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration Initial -Script
Applying explicit migrations: [201404151642086_Initial].
Applying explicit migration: 201404151642086_Initial.
PM>
```

At this point you should see the script. I don't think it includes any seed data. If it does, just remove it before running the script.